Unable to impose rules about sequence of shifts when creating timetable
I am a coder enthusiast, trying to create a timetable generator that follows the rules as below:

each employee must have 1 off day per week
user may input schedule requests prior to the timetable doing its stuff
There should be a minimum of 6 employees working per shift
Employees may have 1 of the following shifts: AM (morning), PM (afternoon), KM (night), off, RM (post-call)
There is a summary row at the end of the table counting the number of employees working per shift, e.g. 6/6/6/2 (6 AM, 6 PM, 6 KM, 2 off/RM)
there are 3 employees taking AM/KM (morning + night) shift per day (compromising of at least 1 senior employee). Each AM/KM shift is followed by KM shift the next day, and RM (post-call) shift the day after, so that one may have AM/KM, KM, RM in consecutive days.

When I tried incorporating rule 5, all hell breaks loose in my code ):

sunday (last column) is not filled with any shifts
no one gets an off day anymore
rule 5 is not enforced
the summary row that counts the number of employees working per shift goes haywire

https://codeshare.io/w9Qewpthis is my whole code, but the main problem started after adding the following snippet:
max_am_km_per_week = 1
    # Assign AM/KM shift (max 3 employees per day, each employee max 1 per week)
    am_km_employees = []
    am_km_seniors = 0  

    # Count the number of senior employees in the AM/KM shift
    for employee in available_seniors:
        if am_km_count[employee] < max_am_km_per_week and len(am_km_employees) < max_am_km_per_day:
            timetable[day][employee] = shifts['Double']
            am_km_count[employee] += 1
            am_km_employees.append(employee)
            am_km_seniors += 1  # Track senior employees assigned to AM/KM shift
    
        # Now, add juniors to the AM/KM shift:
            if am_km_count[employee] < max_am_km_per_week and len(am_km_employees) < max_am_km_per_day:
                # Ensure that if there's less than 1 senior assigned, do not assign juniors until it's met
                if am_km_seniors < 1:
                    continue  # Skip until at least 1 senior is assigned
                timetable[day][employee] = shifts['Double']
                am_km_count[employee] += 1
                am_km_employees.append(employee)
    
    # Remove AM/KM employees from available list for other shifts
    for employee in am_km_employees:
        if employee in available_seniors:
            available_seniors.remove(employee)
        if employee in available_juniors:
            available_juniors.remove(employee)
    
    # Assign "Night" shift the next day for AM/KM employees
    km_employees = []
    if day_index < len(days) - 1:  # Ensure there's a next day
        next_day = days[day_index + 1]
        if next_day not in timetable:
            timetable[next_day] = {}
        
        for employee in am_km_employees:
            if employee not in timetable[next_day]:
                timetable[next_day][employee] = shifts['Night']
                km_employees.append(employee)

    # Remove KM employees from available list for other shifts
    for employee in km_employees:
        if employee in available_seniors:
            available_seniors.remove(employee)
        if employee in available_juniors:
            available_juniors.remove(employee)
    
    # Assign "Post-call" (RM) shift the day after Night shift for AM/KM employees
    rm_employees = []
    if day_index < len(days) - 2:  # Ensure there's a day after next day
        next_next_day = days[day_index + 2]
        if next_next_day not in timetable:
            timetable[next_next_day] = {}
        
        for employee in am_km_employees:
            if employee not in timetable[next_next_day]:
                timetable[next_next_day][employee] = shifts['Post-call']
                rm_employees.append(employee)

    # Remove RM employees from available list for other shifts
    for employee in rm_employees:
        if employee in available_seniors:
            available_seniors.remove(employee)
        if employee in available_juniors:
            available_juniors.remove(employee)

